# Consider the quadratic form q($x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$) := $x_1^2$+$x_3^2$+$2x_1x_2$ $−4x_1x_3$ +$2x_2x_3$, ($x_1,x_2,x_3$)∈ $ℝ^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Consider the quadratic form
q($x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$) := $x_1^2$+$x_3^2$+$2x_1x_2$ $−4x_1x_3$ +$2x_2x_3$, ($x_1,x_2,x_3$)∈ $ℝ^3$.

**(a) Find the symmetric matrix $A$ representing q.**
For (a) I got
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-2\\1&0&1\\-2&1&1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

**(b) Find a corresponding orthogonal matrix $P$ of eigenvectors of $A$.**

For (b) I started by getting the eigenvalues by doing det($A$-$\lambda$$I_3$)=0.

I got $\lambda$ =1, $\lambda$=-2 and $\lambda$=3.

I then found the eigenvector of each eignevalue by doing RREF. For $\lambda$=1 I got (1,2,1), for $\lambda$=-2 I got(1,-1,1) and for $\lambda$=3 I got (-1,0,1).

Am I correct?

**(c) Write down the maximum and minimum values taken by q over the unit vectors in $ℝ^3$.**

Is the **max** simply $\lambda$=3 on unit vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$(-1,0,0). And the **min** is $\lambda$=-2 on the unit vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$(1,-1,1) ?.

Comment: What do you mean ?  Just place the eigenvectors as columns of P , and you're done.

Comment: @WhyHosamWhy oh is that it? Have I the right eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes. They're all correct.  I checked them.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to normalise the vectors? @WhyHosamWhy

Comment: yes, normalize the eigenvectors and make those the columns of $P.$  To check, you should find $P^T P $

Comment: Since it is asking for an orthogonal matrix $P$, then you need to normalize the eigenvectors that you obtained.

Comment: Yes I did that. Thank you. When filling in my orthogonal matrix I fill it in descending order? So the largest eigenvalue first?